# Getting the seconds an alert was in a state

Tags: prometheus

Given an ALERTS query like the below:

```
timestamp(ALERTS{alertstate="firing"})
```

How can you tell how many seconds it was firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figuring out the number of seconds (or, equivalently, the percentage of time) over the past hour/day/whatever that an alert was firing is pretty straightforward:

```
sum_over_time(ALERTS[1h:1s])
```

Or, at lower resolution for efficiency reasons:

```
sum_over_time(ALERTS[1h:10s]) * 10
```

Figuring out when an alert has started firing (or equivalently, how long has it been firing since it started to fire the last time) is somewhat more involved:

```
ALERTS{alertstate="firing"}
  * ignoring(alertstate)
(
  time() - max_over_time(timestamp(ALERTS{alertstate="pending"})[1h:10s])
    or ignoring(alertstate)
  ALERTS{alertstate="firing"} * 3600
)
```

I.e. the time since it was last in state `"pending"` iff it is currently firing. Do note that there's a `1h` range and a default of 3600 in there, meaning that it maxes out at 3600 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, that was straightforward